# Cannot set properties when instantiating React component with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a component(TourSpecPropertiesSection)that will have access to an object from the store. I want it to take the properties of this object and map each one to another component(TourSpecProperty) that will display the name and value for now. I have created both components, but when I attempt to instantiate TourSpecProperty inside of TourSpecPropertiesSection, I cannot set the properties of TourSpecProperty even though I have them defined in an interface. It gives me the error

```
"Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<IOwnProps, never>,ComponentState, ...'"
```

Which has the interface I declared, IOwnProps, in the error message so it seems to be aware of it.

Library versions are

```
"react": "16.4.0",
"redux": "3.7.2",
"typescript": "2.8.3",
```

My classes are

TourSpecPropertiesSection

```
import TourSpec from '../../../models/TourSpec/TourSpec'
import * as React from 'react';
import IRootState from 'redux/rootState';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TourSpecProperty from '../TourSpecProperty'


interface IStateProps {
    SelectedTourSpec: TourSpec | null
}

const getKeys = (tourSpec:TourSpec | null) => {
    if(tourSpec === null){
        return [];
    }
    let keys: string[] = [];
    for(let property in tourSpec){
        keys.push(property);
    }
    return keys;
}
const TourSpecPropertiesSection: React.SFC<IStateProps> = (props) => {    
const keys: string[] = getKeys(props.SelectedTourSpec);
return (
    <div className="tour-spec-section">
                        {/* error shows up here when trying to set name */}
    <TourSpecProperty Name={}/>
            <h3>TourSpec Properties</h3>
                                                                            {/* same error appears here */}
            {keys.map((property: string, index: number) => <TourSpecProperty Name={}/>)}
    </div>
    );
}


const mapStateToProps = (state:IRootState):IStateProps => {
    return {
        SelectedTourSpec: state.TourSpec.SelectedTourSpec
    }
}

export default connect<IStateProps, {}, {}, IRootState>(mapStateToProps)(TourSpecPropertiesSection);
```

and

TourSpecProperty

```
import IRootState from "../../../redux/rootState";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as React from "react";

interface IOwnProps {
    Name: string,
    Value: any
}


const TourSpecProperty: React.SFC<IOwnProps> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Name:{props.Name}
            </div>
            <div>
                Value:{props.Value}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps= (state:IRootState):IOwnProps => {
    return {} as IOwnProps;
}

export default connect<IOwnProps, {}, {}, IRootState>(mapStateToProps)(TourSpecProperty);
```

TourSpecProperty currently has no state even though I've connected it to the store, but it will be accessing and updating a property on my store once I have it instantiating in TourSpecPropertiesSection.

I suspect I have used the wrong type somewhere and the interfaces information is not being passed properly to the React classes, but I cannot determine where that would happen or find a similar issue online/stackoverflow when I looked.

Have I used incorrect types and if so, what ones should I be using? If not, what have I done incorrectly?

Comment: Try converting `Name` (and `Value`) in TourSpecProperty to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

In `TourSpecPropertySection` you are using `<TourSpecProperty name={} />` with `name` as the prop key, while in `TourSpecProperty` you are defining `Name` to be the prop key.

`name != Name`

These two need to match in a case-sensitive way. Either update your props to start with lower case letters or update your usage of `TourSpecProperty` to specify props with upper case first letters.

Comment: Tried that, its still giving the same answer. I pulled up intellisense to check as well and the only properties on the TourSpecProperty element are 'children?', 'key?', and 'ref?'